# Relative path in cmd

Tags: cmd

How to use relative paths in rename or copy commands in cmd file?

```
forfiles /M *.jpg /C "cmd /c move @file /old/@file"
```

I get error "System cannot find the path specified"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use backslashes `\` not forward slashes `/` in pathnames. `/` is a switch identifier, and `\` a path-separator in windows.

Make sure that the destination directory exists.

If the first character in the destination directoryname is \ then that indicates an absoluter directoryname, starting at the root directory. Since you want a relative directory then `old\@file` or `.\old\@file` should work.

Comment: `forfiles /M *.jpg /C "cmd /c move @file old\@file"` same error

Comment: oh, i dont have destinaion folder. I want create them with this bat file, because folders name are based on file modify time. What should i do?

Comment: ask a further question about how to create a directory based on the modify time. You'd need to specify which modify time you want & provide examples of which format you'd want the directory name in & which format you use for time/date,. eg. do you use 1 or two-digit dates, 2 or 4-digit years, does the time format appear in 24-hr or 12-hr (am/pm?), what are the separators & do you include the dayname. OR, preferably, you could use the search facility on the top black bar for `[cmd] create directory time` and read a number of approaches. Tip: `md dirname 2>nul` creates with no error message

Comment: `forfiles` uses the `\ ` as escape character, so you might need to double each of them like `.\\old\\@file`... and there is another problem: `forfiles` expands `@file` to the file name enclosed within `""` stupidly, so you might need to find a way to remove them to not get a target path like `.\old\"filename.ext"`, which is of course invalid...